# What would be better architecture out of these, to scale a system?

Tags: architecture, server, scalability

Lets assume, I am running one machine which has nodejs, websocket service and redis services running on it. I want to distribute the system from scale perspective, which of these two approaches will be better :

1. Run each service on different machine. So two machines for Websocket service behind a load balancer, one machine for nodejs, three machines for Redis.
2. Keep running all services on same machine and now clone this machine to five other machines and run them all behind a load balancer.

I have always worked upon / seen first architecture. But an experienced dev ops person advised me to go for 2nd approach, he says it is easy to manage and scales better.

Also, this is not specific to nodejs, redis etc. I mentioned them to explain better. I want to know in general which is better architecture.

Comment: There is no general better architecture. It depends on your non functional requirements like availability, data consistency, response time, (peak) load, complexity of your business logic, number of machines (number of replications), use cases, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is usually better, especially if you can configure the load balancer to route traffic to a node which has all the data required to process the request. This type of architecture is called [Shared Nothing Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_nothing_architecture) as the different nodes are completely isolated and a failure in one cannot affect another node. This type of architecture scales almost linearly (is not linearly, as you still need to replicate data for high availability, but this can also be done asynchronously if possible).

Alternatively you can have all the data in all nodes... but that might be expensive and replication might become an issue, in particular if you need synchronous replication.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at this issue is thro the AKF Scalability Cube as propounded in the book [The Art of Scalability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134032802). Its a framework to look at scalability using a cube with each of the 3 axis representing diff ways to scale.

x-axis: cloning of services and data so that work can easily be distributed across instances.
y-axis: separation of work responsibility by either data or work. Or a combination of data and work. Provides fault isolation.
z-axis: separation of work based on requests/customers.  Ability to split services by geography

The ideal would be a combination of 1 or more of the scales - depending on your needs. As your needs to up you can start scaling along all 3 dimensions. This will give you almost infinite scale.